# c++ struct definition - how to define a member struct with a single argument in its constructor

Tags: c++, struct

Simple question.  I have a struct which has a member that is also a struct.  The member struct takes one string parameter on construction.  However, in the class definition, the compiler doesn't allow it to be instantiated from there.  I.e. the following is not allowed:

```
struct StructName {
   string       str;
   OtherStruct  other_struct("single string param")   
};
```

So I tried not giving it a parameter which fails because it has to take one:

```
struct StructName {
   string       str;
   OtherStruct  other_struct;

   StructName(string arg);  
};
```

I'm new to C/C++ so I'm sorry if it's an idiotic question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an initialization list:

```
struct StructName {
   string       str;
   OtherStruct  other_struct;

   StructName(): other_struct("init string") { }   
};
```

You can also take an argument to `StructName` and pass it along to `other_struct`, such as:

```
StructName(string arg): other_struct(arg) { }
```